# VIM complex query

Tags: regex, csv, vim

I am using VIM to edit a csv file that looks like this:

```
A00,A01,A02...
A10,A11,A12...
A20,A21,A22...
```

I want to delete every line, from the second occurrence of "," until the end. So i would be left with:

```
A00,A01
A10,A11
A20,A21
```

I tried Ctrl-Shift-v on the second "," in first line, then G to pick all lines, then D to delete until the end. the problem is that Aij are not necessarily of the same length so that didn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`normal` command here is helpful:

```
:%norm! 2f,D
```

does it.

If you want to golf a bit, you can record macro, or use `x@='...'` format. But I feel this way is slightly better than regex solution for the given problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:substitute`, it'll work better than block-visual mode:

```
:%s/\v^.{-},.{-}\zs,.*//
```

With

- `\v` to simply the regex (very magic mode) (`:h /\v`)
- `^` to match the start of line
- `.{-},`: a non greedy match on anything until ... the first comma (`:h /\{`)
- `.{-}\zs,` : the same thing until the second comma, except this time we tell that the match starts at the comma (`\zs` -> Zone Start -> `:h /\zs`).
- and then we replace the match (i.e. starting from the 2nd comma) with nothing.

Comment: This seems to delete the second "," in each line, then match what was the third comma.

Comment: It should be `:%s/\v^.{-},.{-}\zs,.*$//`

Comment: Yes Indeed. Thank you @dNitro.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with `:s`, where you can easily control the number of fields to keep (2 in occurence):

```
:%s/\v^([^,]*\zs,){2}.*//
```

`\zs` is included inside the `()` group, then its position is defined relative to the last found group.